# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, docker, debian, mariadb

I have got the this error on debian testing `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")` while try to connect to the database.

I did the following settings in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:testing

RUN apt update && apt full-upgrade -y \ 
        && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apache2 \
        php \
        libapache2-mod-php \
        mariadb-server \
        php-mysql \
                openjdk-9-jdk \
                git \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start

# Copy the database schema to the /data directory
ADD ./mgsv.sql /tmp/

# Permit root login without password from outside container.
RUN mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION"

# create the default database from the ADDed file.
RUN mysql < mgsv.sql

RUN git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git
```

and the mgsv.sql looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mgsv;
CREATE USER 'mgsv_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mgsvpass';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, CREATE, DROP ON mgsv.* TO 'mgsvuser'@'localhost';
use mgsv;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinfo` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` text NOT NULL,
    `hash` text NOT NULL,
    `synfilename` text NOT NULL,
    `annfilename` text NOT NULL,
    `url` text NOT NULL,
    `session_id` text NOT NULL,
    `annImage`   int(5) NOT NULL,
    `create_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how docker works.

The dockerfile you wrote is not a script. Every command is an independent one, and only has the effect of creating a layer for the final docker image it will generate.
This means that when you run `/etc/init.d/mysql start`, in the following commands you WON'T be able to connect to the mysql service. It is simply not running.

All your data import operations have to be done while you container is `running`, not when it is `building`.

My suggestion is to use a pre-built mysql container image, maybe one you can find here https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ , and after your container is running you can manually create your database.

If you need to make database creation automatically, you need to create a custom image where you update the `entrypoint` or `cmd` of your docker image in order to perform database creation after the DBMS is started, but honestly this is not a very good practice IMHO.